# iOS9 Universal link - linking to app but not reading the URL

Tags: ios, ios9.2, ios-universal-links

So here is my issue.

I have universal link working in my Unity game built for iOS9 too.

The thing is,while I do get directed straight to the app as I wish by clicking "https://www.myappDomain.com..." or "myappDomain://...", it is only by clicking the "myappDomain://" that I get the app opened in the certain screen I want it.

What am I missing here?

NOTE:
I have the apple-app-site-association configured to accept all paths, my associated domains, is configure to request it:

applinks:myappdomain.com

applinks:www.myappdomain.com

Comment: Have you implemented `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` ?

Comment: It is handled by the facebook plugin.

But could "myappDomain://" work if it wasn't???

Comment: I tried implementing application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler with my own UnityAppController. While didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does get called, if I add the continueUserActivity method, the app crashes, at:
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, [NSString stringWithUTF8String:AppControllerClassName]);
With a SIGABRT

Comment: Please provide some more details,like your `apple-app-site-association` file, `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` code etc

Comment: The issue was due to AppsFlyer not implementing the application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler as expected.
I've added my own iOS plugin to do this part and it worked.